# Format array of objects for possible json output for Postman/GET requests

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

So I can't seem to figure this out, so I'm reaching out to see if someone might be able to help me.

**Please let me know what the best output is so that I could use GET to retrieve clean data for the endpoint that I've created**.

**I have the following method**:

```
function instagram_posts(): bool|string
{
    if (!function_exists('is_plugin_active')) {
        include_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');
    }
    if (!is_plugin_active('fh-instagram/autoload.php')) {
        return false;
    }
    if (empty($items = Instagram::get_items_for_api(50))) {
        return false;
    }
    var_dump($items);

    var_dump(json_encode($items));

    return json_encode($items);
}
```

`var_dump($items);` gives me the following output:

```
array(50) {
  [0]=>
  object(Plugin\Instagram\Item)#976 (7) {
    ["id":"Plugin\Instagram\Item":private]=>
  }
  [1]=>
  object(Plugin\Instagram\Item)#1030 (7) {
    ["id":"Plugin\Instagram\Item":private]=>
    string(17) "17842233125750202"
  }
}
```

When I run `var_dump(json_encode($items));` I get the following output:

```
string(151) "[{},{}]"
```

How can I convert my array of objects so that it can transform it to json and then use it within Postman? This is what it currently looks like in Postman:

```
array(50) {
  [0]=>
  object(Plugin\Instagram\Item)#973 (7) {
    ["id":"Plugin\Instagram\Item":private]=>
    string(17) "17992874035441353"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(Plugin\Instagram\Item)#1027 (7) {
    ["id":"Plugin\Instagram\Item":private]=>
    string(17) "17842233125750202"
  }
}
```

It should be outputted such as:

```
[
  {"id": etc..}
]
```

All help will be appreciated!

The instagram_posts method is being use below:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'instagram', '/posts/', [
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'instagram_posts',
    ]);
});
```

So I can use Postman to access the endpoint: `http://headlesscms.com.local/wp-json/instagram/posts`

Comment: If you pass objects through `json_encode()`, only their public properties will be part of the encoded result. Private and protected properties will be discarded and looking at your var_dumps, the id is a private property. The best way to fix this in your case depends on how the `Plugin\Instagram\Item` class works, which we know nothing about. If you can access the id from that class, you could simply iterate through the objects and build an array with the structure you want and encode that instead.

Comment: Thanks @M.Eriksson, I in fact can access the items, what would be the best way to build an array based on all the objects? Would I json_encode after building the array? I can access my Item class using `foreach ($items as $item) $item->get_id()`

Comment: Would it be something like this?

`$result = [];
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $result['id'] = $item->get_id();
    }
    return json_encode($result, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);`

Comment: Almost, but you need to create a multidimensional array, or you're just overwriting the same array key over and over. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the property you want is private, it won't be included in the results of `json_encode()`. Only public properties will.

You need to create a multidimensional array with the structure you want and encode that.

```php
// This is the new array we will push the sub arrays into
$results = [];

foreach($items as $item) {
    $results[] = ['id' => $item->get_id()];
}

return json_encode($results);
```

This will give you a json structure that looks like:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2
    },
    ...
]
```

#### Alternative format

If you only want a list of id's, you might not need to create a multidimensional array, but rather just return a list of ids.

In that case, do this:

```php
$results = [];

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $results[] = $item->get_id();
}

return json_encode($results);
```

That would give you:

```json
[
    1,
    2,
    ...
]
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so much! When I run it in Postman, it comes out as a string such as `"[{\"id\":\"17992874035441353\"},{\"media_type\":\"CAROUSEL_ALBUM\"}]"`. Would you know how to format it so it comes out as an array? Something similar to how `wp-json/wp/v2/posts` outputs using the REST API such as `[{"id":1,"date":"2022-03-10T17:36:39"}]`. Also is there a way to handle slashes? I've tried using `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` as in the docs, but I guess it's not formatting since it's a string output.

Comment: How are you outputting the result? You should also add `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before you output the results to let the client know it is json.

Comment: I'm basically calling `return json_encode($results, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);` at the very end.

Comment: That's how you return the results, not how you output it. Where and how is `instagram_posts()` called? If the result is just echoed, you don't need any `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`. The only reason you see those slashes is because you have the result as a string inside double quotes. That might just be how the client you're using displays it.

Comment: I've just updated the post to include the place where `instagram_posts()` is called, it's  basically a method used to register a route with an endpoint so that my friend can call a GET request later and grab the json data. (It's my first time registering a route and sending data to it, so I hope I did it correctly).

Comment: The function `register_rest_route()` might actually handle the json encoding for you so when you use `json_encode()`, you're encoding it twice. Try using just `return $results;`. I've never used that function so I can't help you with that.